# SQL Server 2008 - Looping

Tags: sql-server-2008, loops

I have a set of scripts that I want to loop thru, a number of times and add the results to a temp table into the columns points_mth1, points_mth2 and points_mth3, but may need to insert a new row for a Customer not already in the table.

A start @EndDate is entered and then I want to run for the next 2 months eg, 2014-02-01, 2014-03-01 & 2014-04-01

How do I add a loop to the below to run for the next 2 months?

```
SET NOCOUNT ON

DECLARE @EndDate DateTime

SET @EndDate = '2014-02-01' 

[set of scripts will be run]
```

The results are then stored in a temp table, where each time it runs, a new column is added eg.points_mth2, and store the figure against the Customerno in the but it the customer does not exist to then insert the customerno:

```
IF object_id(N'tempdb..#temp', N'U') IS NOT NULL     DROP TABLE #temp
SELECT j1.customerno, SUM(points)[points_mth1]        ---> this will store the figures for the first date, then a new column [points_mth2] and [points_mth3]
into #temp
FROM customer j1
JOIN #customer_final j2 ON
j1.customerno= j2.customerno
GROUP BY j1.customerno
```

Comment: You gotta ask a specific question. You're just stating your goals.  What is your obstacle that you need help with?

Comment: You should try to *avoid* looping in SQL - SQL is a set-oriented language. It's great at dealing with data when dealing with all of it. Not so great when you force it to work one row at a time. So, if you could tell us what the data is that we're working with, and what the desired outcome is, we might be able to help you. All you've described so far is the *mechanism* that you wanted to use. In SQL, you try to tell the engine *what you want*, **not** *how to do it*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

not sure what exactly you want, probably here is a start for you:

```
DECLARE @EndDate DATE = '2013-09-30 00:00:00:000';
DECLARE @tmpDate DATE = GETDATE();

WHILE @tmpDate <= @EndDate 
    BEGIN
        PRINT @tmpDate;

        -- do whatever you need here for specific date - @tmpDate

        SET @tmpDate = DATEADD(DAY, 1, @tmpDate);
    END
```